# Piranha CMS MVC tag problem with displaying blocks

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, piranha-cms

So I have been learning Piranha CMS for .Net Core 3.1.

Having read the docs and studied the template I have hit a bit of wall in getting the information from within Blocks to display on the page correctly.

In the Razor Blog Template on the **Page.cs** the developer has used the below code to display the Blocks that the page has on screen

```
    <h1>@Model.Data.Title</h1>

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Data.Blocks)
```

On the **About Me** page on the template website this displays as such:
[Image of what should happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUCb.png)

On my own site, I have it written the same and have assigned some simple text blocks to the page to test it, however I get the following: [My Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZw1o.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what mistake I might be making?

Both the **Startup.cs** and other essential files are fine and don't have any major difference.

The only difference on the site I can see is mine having a lack of styling. But I don't see why that should affect it.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered in the Gitter chat, but I'll answer here as well if someone else has the same question.

### Display templates & Editor templates

The templating system is a built in feature of `ASP.NET Core` and assumes you have the following folders present in you project.

#### MVC

```
Views
Views/DisplayTemplates
Views/EditorTemplates
```

#### Razor Pages

```
Pages
Pages/DisplayTemplates
Pages/EditorTemplates
```

### Calling templates

When you call `DisplayFor()` on a collection of objects, like the code you referenced from the Razor Blog template `ASP.NET` automatically selects the template with the name corresponding to type name. So in this case, if your block is of the type `Piranha.Extend.Blocks.TextBlock` it will try to locate the view file:

```
Pages/DisplayTemplates/TextBlock.cshtml
```

Now if you have your own loop in the view, say if you'd like to add a containing `div` around every block and give a single object into `EditorFor()` the standard rendering of `ASP.NET` will be executed which just prints out the Properties of the given object.

#### Won't work the way your want

```cs
@foreach (var block in Model.Data.Blocks)
{
  <div class="myclass">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => block)
  </div>
}
```

#### Workaround

The simple workaround is to just give in the name of the DisplayTemplate that you want to render the block. This can be easily achieved by writing:

```cs
@foreach (var block in Model.Data.Blocks)
{
  <div class="myclass">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => block, block.GetType().Name)
  </div>
}
```

Best regards

Håkan

Comment: This workaround work when site renders but it does not work for me when I try to render partial view via API call. I have a DisplayTemplate .cshtml file for this type in the same project.
I only get ID and type name displayed. Do you maybe know why?